# Search Function : Error

Tags: php, mysql, html

Im not sure how to correct these errors, can someone help me.

search.php

```
Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\wamp\www\i-document\search.php on line 12
Notice: Undefined index: search in C:\wamp\www\i-document\search.php on line 13
```

After clicking 'search' :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: x in C:\wamp\www\i-document\search.php on line 39
Notice: Undefined variable: construct in C:\wamp\www\i-document\search.php on line 41
```

Thankz.

The codes :

```
<?php

//Get data

$button = $_GET['submit'];
$search = $_GET['search'];

if (!$button)    echo "You didn't submit a keyword."; else {    if (strlen($search)<=1)
      echo "Search term too short";    else    {
      echo "You searched for <b>$search</b><hr size='1'>";

      //connect to database
      mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      mysql_select_db("idoc");


            //explode search term
            $search_exploded = explode(" ",$search);

            foreach($search_exploded as $search_each);
            {

                //Construct Query

                $x++;
                if ($x==1)
                   $construct .= "file_name LIKE '%$search_each%'";
                else
                   $construct .= " OR file_name LIKE '%$search_each%'";

            }


      $construct = "SELECT * FROM document WHERE $construct";
      //echo out construct

     // $construct = "SELECT * FROM document WHERE $construct";
     $run = mysql_query($construct);

     $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

     if ($foundnum==0)
        echo "No results found";
     else
     {
        echo "$foundnum results found!<p>";

        while ($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
        {
         //Get data
         $ref = $runrows['file_ref'];
      $filename = $runrows['file_name'];    $owner = $runrows['owner'];
         $url = $runrows['url'];
         echo "
        <table>   <tr>
    <td> $ref </td>
    <td> $filename </td>
    <td> $owner </td>
    <td><a href='$url'>$url</a></td>
      </tr>    </table>
         ";
        }

     }
  } }
?>

<form id="form1" method="GET" action="search.php">
  <table width="446" height="135" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td height="31" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#990000">
        <span class="style1 style2">
          Search :
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="374" height="96" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#990000">
        <span class="style1 style2">
          <label>
            <div align="left">
              Keyword :
              <input name="search" type="text" id="search" size="40" />
            </div>
          </label>
        </span>
        <td width="56" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#990000">
          <div align="left">
            <input type = "submit" name="submit" value="search" />
          </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: these are no errors! just notices. you did everything right. the compiler just made a notice that you did something that might cause trouble but is syntacticly right.

Comment: Question Answered. Thank you all ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with unknown arrays, you should test if an array key exists before reading it. In your case the error messages say that neither *submit* nor *search* exist.

Use [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) or [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) to check if a array key exists before reading them:

```
// setting default values
$button = '';
$search = '';

// assigning GET parameter values if existing
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $button = $_GET['submit'];
}
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $search = $_GET['search'];
}
```

You can also use the [conditional operator `cond-expr ? true-expr : false-expr`](http://php.net/language.operators) for a more consise notation:

```
$button = isset($_GET['submit']) ? $_GET['submit'] : '';
$search = isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

It means $_GET don't contain index 'submit', before form was send. You can disable Notice error render or add a condition using isset().

After you try to increment and concatenate undefined variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($search_exploded as $search_each);
{

    //Construct Query

    $x++; // this is bad practice because you didn't initialize the $x var before your foreach
    if ($x==1)
        $construct .= "file_name LIKE '%$search_each%'"; //this also "could" cause problems because you didn't define the $construct in the higher scope so that it "might" not be accessable from outside the if statement. BUT sometimes this works
    else
        $construct .= " OR file_name LIKE '%$search_each%'";

}
```

these were the two "notices" php gave you here:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: x in C:\wamp\www\i-document\search.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined variable: construct in C:\wamp\www\i-document\search.php on line 41
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your error_reporting is set to the maximum level, so you'll get a lot of Notice messages too.

'Undefined index' meaning your $_GET[`any`] variables are empty before submit.

'Undefined variable' meaning you are using a previously undefined variable (`$x++`).

It's always a good practice developing at this error_reporting level because you'll get a lot of information about where you should improve your code.

For this example:

```
$x = 0;
$construct = '';
$button = !empty($_GET['submit']) ? $_GET['submit'] : NULL;
$search = !empty($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

These are just Notices, not errors.
However if you want to avoid these, you can check if the variable is passed with isset()

Instead of

```
$button = $_GET['submit'];
if (!$button)
```

Use

```
if (isset($_GET['submit']))
```

Answer (score 0):

It means your search index is missing from your url. Verify you are navigating to an url containing '&search='. If you are submitting the search keyword through a form, verify its method attribute is set to 'get

Comment: I have already set it to 'get'. Can u explain waht u mean by "your search index is missing from your url? thankz"

Comment: Well, if you're using get. You need to access the php script with an URL containing the query variables. Like this: http://www.example.com/script.php?search=keyword. Could you provide the HTML of your form?

Comment: hi, I have added d html codes above. Sorry, dat its messy, im still not used to the question posting method here.

Comment: Fabrik's solution should work then! Have you tried it already?

Answer (score 0):

1. the indexes `submit` and `search` are not defined (they're not in URL). Try instead:

   $button = isset($_GET['submit']) ? $_GET['submit'] : false;
   $search = isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : false;
2. you **NEED** to define variables if you don't want to get `E_NOTICE` on each undefined variable.

   foreach($search_exploded as $search_each) {
                   //defining variables
                   $construct = '';
                   $x = 0;

   ```
               //Construct Query


           $x++;
           if ($x==1)
              $construct .= "file_name LIKE '%$search_each%'";
           else
              $construct .= " OR file_name LIKE '%$search_each%'";


       }
   ```